# How to save "*" string in a variable in unix/bash?

Tags: bash

I have an assignment to write a script that reads a number from the user and prints stars say if the number is 3 then it would print

```
***
**
*
**
***
```

I understand the idea of how to write it, but i try to make a variable that saves * in it but when i echo $variable it would just show all the folders/files in my current place. how do I just save the '*' as a string without it running the function?

Comment: Please show a sample of code that illustrates the problem. You can [edit] your question to include this. Don't forget to format it with the `{}` button on the editing toolbar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
varname='*'
```

Though you have to be careful with where you use it; since globbing occurs after variable expansion, if you expand it carelessly it'll do the glob operation at expand-time instead. Use `echo "$varname"` to print it (note the quotes).

Comment: Thanks alot I forgot the quotes when I print it that was my issue, kinda new to this thanks!

Comment: Note that `variable=*` works the same (it would be a different matter for `array=(*)` vs `array=('*')` though). The main point here is that parameter expansions must be quoted in POSIX shells.

Answer (score 4):

Just quote the variable.

```
$ variable='*'
$ echo $variable
file1 file2 file3
$ echo "$variable"
*
```

Comment: Oh god I forgot I had to put the variable in quotes aswell when I do echo "$variable", thanks man!